# android use zk client with curator to connect zk get data failed with connectionLoss

Tags: java, android, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

zk client: android use curator 4.2

zk server: zk version 3.5.6

problem: when i connect zk to get data from "/" failed with

org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /

```
                class MyThread implements Runnable {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            String ip = "192.168.0.111";
                            System.out.println("start new");
                            ExponentialBackoffRetry retry = new ExponentialBackoffRetry(10000, 3);
                            System.out.println("end new");
                            CuratorFramework curatorFramework = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(ip, retry );
                            System.out.println("end new2");

                            curatorFramework.start();

                            Stat nodeStat = new Stat();
                            byte[] nodeInfo = curatorFramework.getData()
                                    .storingStatIn(nodeStat)
                                    .forPath("/");
                            System.out.println("===node info is:" + new String(nodeInfo));

                            curatorFramework.create().creatingParentContainersIfNeeded()
                                    .withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT)
                                    .withACL(ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE)
                                    .forPath("/nodeTest", "testData".getBytes());
                            System.out.println("wtf");
                            button1.setText("nihaoya");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println( e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i fixed it, just close use System.setProperties(ZooKeeperSaslClient.ENABLE_CLIENT_SASL_KEY, "false");

Answer (score 0):

Connection strings in ZooKeeper are not merely the IP address. You must also include the client port (usually 2181). Also, you should include all servers in the ensemble (I assume you have 3). So, a common connection string is `111.111.111.111:2181,222.222.222.222:2181,333.333.333.333:2181` (of course, use your IP addresses).

Comment: oh, it's not work, and  the zk server was running in the virtual machine which is ubuntu 18.04. the android machine was android studio's virtual device. and the app err response is the same when i  stop the zk server. it's look like the zk server is not running. but what confused me is that when i start another virtual machine and start an zk client which is relize with golang, it can connect to the zk server and work well